# Identifying which radio button was clicked in firebase database

Tags: javascript, html

so I have created 3 radio buttons which are successfully saving in firebase database. However, I cannot identify in the firebase which one is saved, since it shows like all 3 are chosen. How could I maybe change my code or add something to it to see which option was clicked?

[this is what i see in firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ6ps.png)

html

```
<form id="contactForm">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="q1"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="q2"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="q3"> Other

          <p class="full">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </p>



        </form>
```

Java Script

```
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');


document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);


function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault();



  var q1 = getInputVal ('q1');
  var q2 = getInputVal ('q2');
  var q3 = getInputVal ('q3');




  saveMessage(q1, q2, q3 );


  document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'block';


  setTimeout(function(){
    document.querySelector('.alert').style.display = 'none';
  },3000);


  document.getElementById('contactForm').reset();
}

function getInputVal(id){
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}


function saveMessage( q1, q2, q3){
  var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
  newMessageRef.set({

    q1:q1,
    q2:q2,
    q3:q3,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is your sending all the values to firebase, not just the one that is selected.

```
function saveMessage(){
  const GENDER = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
  var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();

  newMessageRef.set({
    gender: GENDER
  });
}
```

Comment: And if for example I have several name inputs, how would that work? For example I have gender, age and education

Comment: Hello. When someone doesnt choose an option, submit button becomes unavailable. Do you know how to fix that ?